# Android AsyncTask still hanging UI

Tags: android, asynchronous, jsoup

I'm using an AsyncTask to grab some data from the web, but it still seems to be hanging the UI while fetching the data.

My code: https://gist.github.com/MasterEjay/10005933

The ThreadParse class is inside my main class, and the initWebView method is also inside of the main class, not ThreadParse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should launch the ASynctask using `execute` method.

With your code you just call the method in the main thread. `execute` will create a new thread for the Asynctask.

```
public void initWebView(String link) {
    ThreadParse parse = new ThreadParse();
    parse.execute(link);
}
```

If you **really** need to do something to the UI in `doInBackground` you should use `runOnUIThread`

I taked this code block as example

```
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    currentPage = 1;
    totalPages = 1;
    Toast.makeText(Thread.this, "You are on " + currentPage + " of " + totalPages, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css", e.html(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    return;
}
```

Here, to let it work you should do

```
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    YourTopActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        currentPage=1;
        totalPages=1;
        Toast.makeText(Thread.this,"You are on "+currentPage+" of "+totalPages,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).

        show();

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css",e.html(),"text/html","utf-8",null);
    });
    return;
}
```

Same for other things which works with UI elements.

[`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) documentation.

Here `YourTopActivity` is needed because you should use `runOnUiThread` method of `Activity` and you are inside `Asynctask` class.

Anyway, you should rethink your code to use [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) and [`onPreExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29)

Comment: When I tried that, I got an " Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" error when I tried to make a Toast.

Comment: It's caused by the fact you can't edit UI from a different thread. Everytime you need to work with UI use runOnUIThread (or better, use onPostExecute/onPreExecute which is called in the UI thread)

Comment: No, I'm using 2.3 or later. And can you give me an example of how to use the runOnUIThread? Not that experienced with Android.

Comment: Yes, with your current code your application will not work in Android >= 3.0 anyway. I will edit the answer with runOnUIThread.

Comment: So should I just bump the minSDkVersion in the mainfest?

Comment: Edited, anyway no. If you run your application in Android >= 3.0 you will get an exception (now no with the execute method call.).